# Filter a collection with like operator from a string collection

Tags: c#, linq, collections

I have a string collection:

```
["1-","2-","4-"]
```

I also have a collection of classes.

Class:

```
public class ProductionParameter
    {
        public string CompanyCode { get; set; }
        public string UnitCode { get; set; }
        public string ItemDescriptionLocal { get; set; }
        public string ItemDescriptionEnglish { get; set; }
        public string ConsumedItemDescriptionLocal { get; set; }
        public string ConsumedItemDescriptionEnglish { get; set; }
        public string LotCategory1Description { get; set; }
        public string LotCategory2Description { get; set; }
        public string LotCategory3Description { get; set; }
        public string LotCategory1Code { get; set; }
        public string LotCategory2Code { get; set; }
        public string LotCategory3Code { get; set; }
        public string LineCode { get; set; }
        public string LineCodeDisplay { get; set; }
        public string ItemUOM1 { get; set; }
        public string ItemUOM2 { get; set; }
        public string ConsumedItemUOM1 { get; set; }
        public string ConsumedItemUOM2 { get; set; }
        public string WorkShift { get; set; }
    }
```

I want to get all the members of the collection where the LineCode property is within the string collection but with like operation.

Example: I want to check every class in the list of productionparmaters and keep only the instances where the LineCode property is :

```
(LIKE '1-%' OR like '2-%' OR LIKE '4-%')
```

Comment: Could you complete your question?

Comment: Please provide more information,question is incomplete

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `LINQ` to do that:
Assuming `stringCollection` is the the string collection from your post and `lstProductionParameter` is the objects list collection you refer.

After the edit of your question, I'll give two possible answers:

1) If You need to check if the value or LineCode HAS ANY of the values in the string, you can go this way:

```
var lstProductionParameterFiltered = lstProductionParameter.Where(c => stringCollection.Any(s => c.Linecode.Contains(s)));
```

In case you area using StringCollection class (I'd prefer use a List or Array for this btw) you could cast the StringCollection like this:

```
var lstProductionParameterFiltered = lstProductionParameter.Where(c => ((IEnumerable<string>)stringCollection).Any(s => c.Linecode.Contains(s)));
```

2) If you need to check if any of the stringCollection has the LineCode, you can go this another way:

```
var lstProductionParameterFiltered = lstProductionParameter.Where(c => stringCollection.Contains(c.Linecode));
```

Comment: Are you sure it works with Any? the StringCollection is a StringCollection Class from properties in a VS solution

Comment: i updated the question a little bit more. Please check at the end.

Comment: In that case you will go with the first way. And yes, StringCollections has a Contains method. If you need to operate more with LINQ and StringColection you always can cast it as IEnumerable<string>

Comment: Properties.Settings.Default..... doesnt seem to have ANY method...i will try with contains

Comment: Ups! My bad! You are right! The StringCollection do not has access to that, but you could cast like in the comment above, I'll edit the answer.

Comment: it works ok! @frikinside. Is there a way to check if the filterlist is empty and then make the where?

Comment: @e4rthdog Sure, you can check if the collectionCount is > 0 before filter or check it in the filter (i think is better check that before, but i'll put anyway: var lstProductionParameterFiltered = lstProductionParameter.Where(c => stringCollection.Count == 0 || ((IEnumerable<string>)stringCollection).Any(s => c.Linecode.Contains(s)));

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Contains` in `Where`. This will compare the whole string:

```
var filteredParameters = productionParameters
    .Where(pp => strings.Contains(pp.LineCode));
```

If you want to check if it starts with it you can use `Any`+`string.StartsWith`:

```
var filteredParameters = productionParameters
    .Where(pp => strings.Any(s => (pp.LineCode ?? "").StartsWith(s)));
```

Note that this> `??` is the [null-coalescing operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) which i've used to handle the case that this property can be `null`. Othwerwise it would raise a `NullReferenceException`.

If it's not a `List<string>` (as i have presumed) but a `StringCollection` from a config-file, you have to use `Enumerable.Cast` to support LINQ:

```
var strings = stringCollection.Cast<string>();
var filteredParameters = productionParameters
    .Where(pp => strings.Any(s => (pp.LineCode ?? "").StartsWith(s)));
```

Comment: i need to check the obj.Property if it is like any of the string collection

Comment: @e4rthdog: after reading your edited question i have edited my answer.